# Creating Android Quiz with random Q and multiple A

Tags: android, database, sqlite, random

I'm trying to make a simple quiz app. I need to make the question to pop out in random order. Now, I have no problem with working the layout and button, the concept of this little quiz is also familiar to me because I have done it in VB with MySQL, I'm just too unfamiliar with working with sqlite. Now, my question is : 
1. Can I create an Android app with MySql?
2. If I can't, how can I make/code a sqlite database with fields like this:

> ID | Question | OptionA | OptionB | RightQuestion

I will match the string in RightQuestion to the radio button id to validate each answer the user clicked.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957682/how-to-random-questions-in-the-quiz-using-json-array-in-android), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194258/android-how-can-i-display-random-buttons-to-a-simple-quiz-game/15194323#15194323) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205137/android-how-can-i-get-the-right-list-of-answers-in-a-quiz-game-with-random-ques), but none of them is what I'm looking for. I need for some help

Comment: This question discusses using a mySQL database to hold your official list of questions and how to sync it with a local sqlLite database on the device. Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511402/how-to-sync-sqlite-database-on-android-phone-with-mysql-database-on-server

Comment: Actually I would like to keep it offline on my first try because I'm not really familiar with this yet

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, you can use mysql via a web server, which you can send request to the sever and the server will interactive with mysql.

On the other hand, just refer to here for sqlite programming in Android [Using the Android SQLite Database](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)